Determine the strike price of a Bermuda callable bond
considering a 10 year zero coupon callable bond that can only be redeemed by the issuer once a year on a fixed date. Once the bond is redeemed after $T$ years or matured at the end of 10 years, the issuer will payoff the Principal amount $A$, as well as $5\% \times T \times A$ yields.
I would like to pricing this callable bond, but how to determine the strike price of this callable bond?

Bond pricing depends a lot on its credit risk, not just the promised cash flows. But the fixed strike prices of the call appears to already be given by the formula in your question?

Thank you for your replying, let us ignore the credit/default risk, could you tell me what strike price should i use?  $A/(1+5%)$?
